# tar checkpoint action exec write to file

Tags: command-line, ssh, tar

I want to use tar and ssh to send files as part of automated processes on ubuntu 14.04. I can send the file as follows:

```
tar -c  large_test_file_10MB.txt.tar.gz | ssh -q 172.16.200.211 'tar -x'
```

But this doesn't allow me to monitor the transfer progress. I have managed to tar a file and write the progress to stdout with the command below:

```
tar -czf large_test_file_10MB.txt.tar.gz large_test_file_10MB.txt --record-size=10K --checkpoint=100 --checkpoint-action=exec='echo $TAR_CHECKPOINT"0kiB"'; FROMSIZE=`du -sk large_test_file_10MB.txt | cut -f 1`; printf "%dkiB\n" $FROMSIZE
```

it produces the following output:

```
1000kiB
2000kiB
3000kiB
4000kiB
5000kiB
6000kiB
7000kiB
8000kiB
9000kiB
9768kiB
```

But this doesn't allow me to pipe the file to ssh and view the progress at the same time. If I change the --checkpoint-action=exec command from

```
echo $TAR_CHECKPOINT"0kiB"
```

to

```
echo $TAR_CHECKPOINT"0kiB" >> progress.txt
```

the output just changes to

```
1000kiB >> progress.txt
2000kiB >> progress.txt
3000kiB >> progress.txt
4000kiB >> progress.txt
5000kiB >> progress.txt
6000kiB >> progress.txt
7000kiB >> progress.txt
8000kiB >> progress.txt
9000kiB >> progress.txt
9768kiB >> progress.txt
```

how can I get the --checkpoint-action=exec command to rather write to file than to stdout?

I know that I could possibly do this with a tool such as pv, but I would prefer to be able to run the command without installing additional software.

Comment: How about `'sh -c "echo $TAR_CHECKPOINT"0kiB" >> progress.txt"'`?

Comment: That worked perfectly! Please add it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual, it looks like `tar` doesn't invoke a shell, but performs some field splitting and expansion by itself on the `exec` argument. From the section on [Running External Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC55):

> Certain GNU tar operations imply running external commands that you
>   supply on the command line. One of such operations is checkpointing,
>   described above [...]
>
> Whenever such operation is requested, `tar` first splits the supplied
>   command into words much like the shell does. It then treats the first
>   word as the name of the program or the shell script to execute and the
>   rest of words as its command line arguments. The program, unless given
>   as an absolute file name, is searched in the shell's `PATH`.
>
> Any additional information is normally supplied to external commands
>   in environment variables, specific to each particular operation. For
>   example, the `--checkpoint-action=exec` option, defines the
>   `TAR_ARCHIVE` variable to the name of the archive being worked upon.
>   You can, should the need be, use these variables in the command line
>   of the external command.

So, if you need other shell syntax like redirection, you'll need to invoke a shell:

```
tar ...  --checkpoint-action=exec='sh -c "echo $TAR_CHECKPOINT"0kiB" >> progress.txt"'
```

(The odd quoting works: `sh` should still get a single string `echo  [...]0kiB > progress.txt` as the argument following `-c`.)